# Calculate `total ` and update `total=quantity*price` in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-changedetection, angular-template-form

I want to calculate something like this: `total= quantity*price` and update the `total` when `quantity` or `price` changes.

[template-output-snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87eBR.png)

**app.component.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="editform" (ngSubmit)="edisale()" class="col s12" materialize>
    <div class="form-group">
        <table align="center" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr style="color:black;">
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>
                    <th>Subtotal</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr formArrayName="products" class="group" style="cursor: pointer" *ngFor="let sale of editform.get('products').value; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control" id="p_unit_price " type="number" class="validate" [value]="sale.p_unit_price" ng-change="tot()">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="p_quantity" id="p_quantity" name="p_quantity" [value]="sale.p_quantity" ng-change="tot()">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-field col s2">
                            <input class="form-control" formControlName="p_description" id="p_description" type="text" class="validate" [value]="sale.p_description">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="p_subtotal" id="p_subtotal" name="p_subtotal" [value]="(sale.p_subtotal)">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s2" style="float: right;">
            Total: {{Total}} ALL
            <input class="form-control" formControlName="total" id="total" type="text" class="validate" [value]="totale">
        </div>
        <div class="form-control" class="input-field col s2" style="float: right;">
            Amount Paid:
            <input class="form-control" formControlName="amount_paid" id="amount_paid" type="text" class="validate">
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s2" style="float: right;">
            Subtotal:
            <input formControlName="subtotal" id="subtotal" type="text" class="validate" [value]="Total">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
tot() {
    return this.products
        .map(pro => pro.p_unit_price * pro.p_quantity)
        .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}
```

When I change the `quantity` or `price`, nothing changes in the `total`.

**Can anyone suggest any idea or explain what is the problem in my code?**

Thank you

Comment: There is a ton wrong here... Since you're using reactive forms, I suggest you start by learning about [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) and moving on from there. Once you have your form set up properly, you should be able to figure out how to display the total correctly. You don't even need a `change` event handler. We also don't use `ng-change` in angular 2+. We use `(change)="doSomething()"` or `(ngModelChange)="doSomething()"` depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

add (change)="somefunction()" and create two way binding using [(ngModel)]="var1" in your input

```
export class ComponentName {

var1;var2; var3;
  constructor(
  ) { }
functionName(){
// when you change your input this method is called and then manipulate your variable.
}

}
```